# What is Just in Haskell and why wouldn't this function work without it?

Tags: haskell, types, option-type

I have the following function that acts like an index operator:

```
let {
  index :: [a]->Int->Maybe a
  index [] i = error "Empty list"
  index l i = if i <= ((length l) - 1) && i >= 0 then 
      Just(l !! i) 
    else
      error "Index out of bounds"
}
```

Now, initially i wrote this without using `Just` (and i still don't understand what it is after googling):

```
let {
  index :: [a]->Int->Maybe a
  index [] i = error "Empty list"
  index l i = if i <= ((length l) - 1) && i >= 0 then
      (l !! i) 
    else
      error "Index out of bounds"
}
```

To me it the above function makes perfect sense. Because here i have a function that accepts a list of 'generic type' `a` and an `Int` which is the index and returns `Maybe` value of type `a` or throws runtime exception. However, i don't understand the bit where GHCi tells me this:

```
<interactive>:1:120:
Couldn't match type `a' with `Maybe a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for index :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
      at <interactive>:1:34
Expected type: [Maybe a]
  Actual type: [a]
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `l'
In the expression: (l !! i)
```

Now, why is GHCi getting confused with the type of `l` and why is it expecting a list of type `Maybe a`? Finally, how does `Just` resolve the problem?

Comment: Code-Guru, now my code looks soothing to the eye after your edit :)

Comment: Do you actually prefer to write your definitions on single lines as you originally posted?

Comment: Actually, i would never write such one-liners because i come from a C++/VB.NET background. Since Haskell gives me options to either do write-compile-execute or just write-execute, the laziness in me prefers the second option. Plus, i have just started learning it, so only 'toy programs' will be written like this. Maybe i do not know if i can split my code across multiple lines in GHCi, do i?

Comment: LYAH has a decent explanation of Maybe, Just, and Nothing for beginners. http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've specifically stated in your type annotation that your function `index` returns a `Maybe a`.

Maybe is a data type defined in Haskell thusly:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

That is, it has two value constructors, `Just :: a -> Maybe a` and `Nothing :: Maybe a`. Thus, in order for you function to work correctly, it must return either a `Just a` or a `Nothing`.

This also means that you should be able to remove your error statements with a bit of thought and encode the actual error in the `Nothing` (ie. we were out of bounds, no element here!) and only return a result `Just a` if it makes sense.

Comment: For the sake of symmetry, it could be nice to write `Nothing :: Maybe a` instead of `Nothing` in the sentence about constructors, since you've given the type of `Just`, in case OP thinks the two are different beasts.

Comment: Right, i will read even more about value-ctors, datatypes and type-classes...and i thought Haskell was going to be a joy-ride... :)

Comment: Types are very important. If you are unsure, you can leave out type annotations and let ghc figure the types of your functions out for you.

Answer (score 2):

You told GHC the return type of `index` as `Maybe a`. That means that `(l !! i)` (a value returned by `index`) must be of type `Maybe a`.

Since `(l !! i)` is selecting a single element out of the list `l`, that means `l` must be of type `[Maybe a]` in order for one of its elements to be `Maybe a`.

But `l` is the first argument to `index`, which you have also told GHC is typed `[a]`.

That's exactly your error. GHC is trying to compile an index into a `[Maybe a]` to get a `Maybe a`, but instead it's found the thing being indexed is a `[a]`.

The reason `Just` fixes this, is that `Just` is of type `a -> Maybe a`. So when you say `Just (l !! i)`, GHC now sees you indexing a `[a]` to get an `a`, and then applying `Just` to that which results in a `Maybe a`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, [Data.Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html):

> The Maybe type encapsulates an optional value. A value of type Maybe a either contains a value of type a (represented as Just a), or it is empty (represented as Nothing).

If you are looking for a type `Maybe Int` then your function will return either `Nothing`, or `Just Int`.

> It is a simple kind of error monad, where all errors are represented by Nothing.

Essentially if `Nothing` is returned then something has happened which has resulted in the function not being able to find a result. The `Just` qualifier allows you to operate on these `Maybe` types.